# Erlang: Getting list of all nodes on multi-host cluster

Tags: erlang, distributed

You can use `net_adm:names()` to get the names of all nodes on the host's epmd. However, what if your cluster consisted of a second host (and therefore a second epmd). How could you get the list of all nodes on both hosts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `net_adm:world/0` might be of help.

It "calls `names(Host)` for all hosts which are specified in the Erlang host file `.hosts.erlang`, collects the replies and then evaluates `ping(Node)` on all those nodes. Returns the list of all nodes that were, successfully pinged.

More information: http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html#world-0